# Facebook mobile web returns 'Your link could not be found' when sharing a URL

Tags: facebook, url, mobile, web, sharing

When users try to share a URL on facebook mobile web, sometimes the page returns the following message: 'Your link could not be found' and a text input to manually insert the URL

1. Sharing URL that works:
   https://m.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://dishenvy.com/dish/pollo-garnachas-gran-electrica-brooklyn
2. Sharing URL that doesn't work:
   https://m.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://dishenvy.com/dish/samgyupsal-hahm-ji-bach-new-york-

Code I'm using:

```
<a class="fb_share" name="fb_share" type="icon" share_url="<?php echo urldecode($shareUrl) ?>">                                               
<script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the url you pass is accessible to Facebook. Not sure why, but their mobile site seems to validate the url but their non-mobile site does not seem to care.  If you have code generating the link you pass to facebook and the host corresponds to a server behind a firewall or private network (such as a test or dev server), this error will often happen.

Answer (score 1):

According to the debugger the two url example that you posted work the same:

- [First](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://dishenvy.com/dish/pollo-garnachas-gran-electrica-brooklyn)
- [Second](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://dishenvy.com/dish/samgyupsal-hahm-ji-bach-new-york-1)

So I don't know how to help you with that.

What I can tell you though is that you are using a deprecated api.
The facebook "sharer" is no longer supported as it states [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/):

> The Share button has been deprecated in favor of the Like button, and
>   will no longer be supported. Please use the Like button whenever
>   possible to drive maximum traffic to your apps.

And [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/):

> **What happened to the old Share button?**
>
> We deprecated the Share Button when we launched the Like button,
>   because the Like button improves clickthrough rates by allowing users
>   to connect with one click, and by allowing them to see which of their
>   friends have already connected.

That may be a cause for the inconsistency you are experiencing.
My advise to you is to stop using this deprecated api and move to the Like button.

Comment: Nitzan Tomer, thanks for your answer. That explains a lot. But my client wants to share a review followed by a short text manually introduced.
I guess I'll have to explain that it's not possible to do that without using a deprecated method.

Thanks!

Comment: The [like button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) lets the user enter text for the like, so I don't understand what you're missing.

Comment: Yes! I just realized! Thanks!

Comment: I updated my code. Now I have a 'like button' but it links me to m.facebook.com/share.php..... , too and I get the same result. I think that the mobile web has the problem here....

Comment: Can you edit your original question with the code you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I think facebook check your sharing page found or not on the server. Your first url found on the server (It means first url return the page). Second url doesn't return the page. The second url return the empty page for this reason facebook return this message. **'Your link could not be found'**

Click the link :

> 1. http://dishenvy.com/dish/pollo-garnachas-gran-electrica-brooklyn  =    Page found
> 2. http://dishenvy.com/dish/samgyupsal-hahm-ji-bach-new-york-       =    Page not found

So share correct url on the facebook

Answer (score -2):

https://m.facebook.com/sharer.php?m2w&u=http://dishenvy.com/dish/samgyupsal-hahm-ji-bach-new-york-

For mobile view you want to add **m2w** to the url.

Comment: Does not work, sorry.  I think FB might have removed that parameter.